# How to change icons on Google Play and home screen of Android?

Tags: android, icons, smartphone, google-play

I'm android application developer and I want to know how to change my android icon after downloading from Google Play.

I mean, the icon of my application which you can see on Google Play and the icon of my application which you can see on home screen of your android smartphone are different.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The 512x512 icon you upload to the developer console (when you publish the app) is the one that will be seen in Google Play. The 36x36, 48x48, 72x72, and 96x96 icons you put in your `drawable` resource folders are what will show up on the device homescreen/app drawer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried and am waiting for a reflection of that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change your app's Google Play image after you published it. So make sure to make it right in the first time.

Comment: what about in 2023 ?